# under HTML table Autocomplete for HtmlEditor Control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui

I have a Html table having multiple rows with one drop down and one textbox control.
I want auto complete function for that text box.I implemented the following code for auto complete but it is firing for only first row.The rows are added Dynamically (in jquery) its not workig for those rows.

CODE:

```
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover datatable-highlight" id="tWDE_Items">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>                                 
                                <th style="display:none">ItemId</th>                                
                                <th>Item Name</th>                                  
                                <th>UOM</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var Item in Model.Data_Wde_ItemGrid)
                            {
                                <tr class="datarow">

                                    <td style="display:none">@Item.Item_Id</td>

                                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => Item.Item_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) </td>

                                    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Item.UOM_Id, new SelectList(Item.UOMDetails, "UomId", "UomName"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "UomId" })</td> 
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Java Script :

```
 $('#Item_Item_Name').autocomplete({

    source: function (request, response) {
        debugger;
        var param = { ItemName: $('#Item_Item_Name').val() };
        $.ajax({
            url: "/WDE/GetAutoCompleteItemList",
            data: JSON.stringify(param),
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        val: item.split('÷')[0],
                        label: item.split('÷')[1]

                    }
                }))
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    },
    change: function (e, i) {
        if (i.item) {

        }
        else {
            $('#Item_Item_Name').val('');
            $('#Item_Item_Id').val('');
        }
    },
    select: function (e, i) {
        debugger;
        $('#Item_Item_Name').val(i.item.label);
        $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(2).html(i.item.val);

    },
    minLength: 1
});
```

Comment: Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html (and `$('#Item_Item_Name').autocomplete({` will only ever select the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Your `autocomplete()` call works only on the elements that are in the dom the time you call it. So for dynamically added elements you'll need the call the function again (after the new row was added).

One more thing to notice is that any call using the element id (`$('#Item_Item_Name')`) will work only for the first element with that id, because ids are meant to be unique. So you'll need to change the selector to get the input from the new row.

Create a function that inits the `autocomplete` And after every row you add, call that function on the element you want.

```
function initAutoComplete(elem) {
    $(elem).autocomplete({ /* the same as you use now */ });
}
// after you addded the new row
initAutoComplete($(newRow).find('.autocopmlete-input'));
```

Comment: Bro its works for adding rows before auto complete. after auto complete we add means its not working.

Comment: When ever i added the new row it hits the function initAutoComplete, but i press any key its not hit the autocomplete method.